# "bundler: failed to load command: thin" on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, thin, locomotivecms

I'm using Ruby 2.2.7, and Rails 3.2.21, and trying to deploy an with gem:  `locomotive_cms` of version: `~> 2.5.7` on Heroku, and it gets deployed successfully, but I'm facing the following error:

> 2017-08-12T23:33:13.732440+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: thin (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/thin)
>   2017-08-12T23:33:13.732490+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:6:in `response_call'

And with that, it produces this too:

> Heroku::API::Errors::ErrorWithResponse: Expected(200) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request)

I have `thin` in my Gemfile which is necessary for locomotivecms according to its documentation.

I have been on other similar questions too, but I'm still unable to solve my problem. I have Ruby version: `2.2.7`, and while it is saying: `/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/thin`

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.2.7"

gem 'rails', '3.2.21'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'locomotive_cms', '~> 2.5.7', :require => 'locomotive/engine'
gem 'dotenv-rails'

gem 'savon', '~> 2.3.0' # SOAP client for pulling in events
gem 'twitter', '5.8.0'
gem 'twitter-text'
gem 'whenever', require: false


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'compass-rails',  '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '~> 1.2.4'
end

group :development do
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'pry'
end


# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

# To use on Heorku
gem 'locomotive-heroku', '~> 0.1.0', :require => 'locomotive/heroku'
gem 'thin'
```

Gemfile.lock:

You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/Arslan-Ali-Butt/640c1ec1750d17c9803e12a492f35c4e

Comment: just an fyi - You are going to run into all kind of issues if you are using rails 3.x.x and ruby 2.2.x. Use a CMS that supports rails 4.x.

Comment: What else is in your Gemfile? And what's in Gemfile.lock?

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge I have updated my question with Gemfile, and a linke to Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry in advance for the bad news.

I've taking a look at your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock, and also at the PR   https://github.com/locomotivecms/locomotive-heroku/pull/11 and the latest 2.5.x branch of locomotive_cms at https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/tree/v2.5.x. You've reached the end of functionality due to the lack of maintenance on the versions of the Gems that you depend on.

`locomotive_cms` has been renamed to `locomotivecms` and bumped to version 3+. The `locomotive_cms` gem is no longer maintained. Not only that, but it's no longer compatible with a bunch of the other dependencies you're using, namely excon.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "excon":
  In Gemfile:
    locomotive_cms was resolved to 2.5.8, which depends on
      fog (~> 1.12.1) was resolved to 1.12.1, which depends on
        excon (~> 0.23.0)

    locomotive-heroku was resolved to 0.1.0, which depends on
      heroku-api (~> 0.3.23) was resolved to 0.3.23, which depends on
        excon (~> 0.44)
```

You're going to want to go through the upgrade guide at https://locomotive-v3.readme.io/docs/upgrade-to-v3.

Comment: Yes, I have contacted with Heorku team, and indeed this is reason. `locomotive_cms` isn't compatible with the latest version of Heroku API.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) (place a file named Procfile in the root of your app), to tell Heroku to use thin, like so:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
```

That will allow you to run thin in production on Heroku. I assume that your Gemfile is properly configured

The second message points to a bad request according to [Heroku API guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference), but it's hard to tell how it is connected to the first error message.

Comment: A Procfile is already there with the contents: `web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV`

Comment: What version of Thin are you using?

Comment: It's `1.7.2`. I haven't mentioned it specifically in my Gemfile though.

Comment: Did you check the following user guide: https://locomotive-v3.readme.io/docs/heroku I do not see in this guide where think should be added to the gemfile (or you might be using an older version of Locomotive)

Comment: I'm using Locomotive CMS version: `2.5.7` as mentioned in the question, and its documentation you can find here: http://doc.locomotivecms.com/